# formatting an AVC/H.264 mdat

Tags: mp4, h.264

Can anyone tell me or point me to a section of the specification(s) that clearly demonstrates how from an elementary stream with a series of NALUs how these should be written into a ISO BMFF mdat?

I can see looking at samples and other code that I should have something like: AUD, SPS, PPS, SEI, VideoSlice, AUD etc etc

Things that are not entirely clear to me:

1. If the SPS and PPS are also stored out of band in the AVCC are they required in the mdat?
2. If they are required in the mdat when/where should they be written? e.g. just prior to an IDR?
3. What is the requirement for AUDs?
4. If I am generating sample sizes for the trun is the calcuation for this? In the example I am working to recreate the first sample in the trun has a size of 22817 however if I look at the first sample in the mdat the NALU size prefix is 22678. The value in the trun appears to be the size of all the NALUs + sizes up to and including the first sample (see my example below)

>

```
1 0016E405 (1500165) - box.Size
2 6D646174 (mdat) - box.Type
3 00000002 (2) NAL Size
4 0910 - (2) AUD @ 5187
5 00000025 (37)
6 27640020 AC248C0F 0117EF01 10000003 00100000 078E2800 0F424001 E84EF7B8 0F844229 C0 (37) @ 5193 SPS
7 00000004 (4)
8 28DEBCB0 (4) PPS
9 0000000B (11)
10 06000781 36288029 67C080 (? SEI ?)
11 0000000C (12)
12 06010700 00F00000 03020480 (? SEI is type 6)
13 0000002D (45) @ 5269
14 060429B5 00314741 393403CA FFFC8080 FA0000FA 0000FA00 00FA0000 FA0000FA 0000FA00 00FA0000 FA0000FF 80 (SEI ??)
15 00005896 (22678)
16 25888010 02047843 00580010 08410410 0002….. 22678 bytes video @ 5322
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the SPS and PPS are also stored out of band in the AVCC are they required in the mdat?

No

> If they are required in the mdat when/where should they be written? e.g. just prior to an IDR?

Yes, if you choose to include them, but there is no reason to

> What is the requirement for AUDs?

They are optional

> If I am generating sample sizes for the trun is the calcuation for this?

The number of bytes in the access unit (AU, aka frame). Which may contain more than one NALU. SPS/PPS/SEI/AUD all counted toward the AU size. The 4 byte size prefixed to each NALUs is also counted in the AU size recored in the trun.

```
bytes
    4 | 3 00000002 (2) NAL Size
    2 | 4 0910 - (2) AUD @ 5187
    4 | 5 00000025 (37)
   37 | 6 27640020 AC248C0F 0117EF01 10000003 00100000 078E2800 0F424001 E84EF7B8 0F844229 C0 (37) @ 5193 SPS
    4 | 7 00000004 (4)
    4 | 8 28DEBCB0 (4) PPS
    4 | 9 0000000B (11)
   11 | 10 06000781 36288029 67C080 (? SEI ?)
    4 | 11 0000000C (12)
   12 | 12 06010700 00F00000 03020480 (? SEI is type 6)
    4 | 13 0000002D (45) @ 5269
   45 | 14 060429B5 00314741 393403CA FFFC8080 FA0000FA 0000FA00 00FA0000 FA0000FA 0000FA00 00FA0000 FA0000FF 80 (SEI ??)
    4 | 15 00005896 (22678)
22678 | 16 25888010 02047843 00580010 08410410 0002….. 22678 bytes video @ 5322
------| 
22817 | <- bytes total
```

Comment: thanks for the nice concise answer that looks spot on